# Opening a link located in the same position across several sites

Tags: jquery, web, automation

This is more from a user perspective. So say I access 10 sites that are structured identically like this site: [example](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/advisor/advisor.html)

Now, I have each of the 10 sites as tabs in my browser. Is there any way I can click on, say, "Installation instructions" on all 10 tabs at once? What I'm hoping to is avoid going through each tab, one by one, to click on the "Installation instructions" link.

Comment: You could accomplish it using _web scrapers_ . There are many Open Source frameworks out there you can use depending on your background. [PHP/Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) & [Python/Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) are some options. but try to pick any tool you choose with learning curve in mind.

Comment: No experience whatsoever using PHP or Python. I'm somewhat proficient in R and Stata. How steep is the learning curve for this "simple" task?

Comment: Better to avoid using these tools, as they are _serious_ scrapers. If you are allowed to use a **visual** browser automation tool, Try [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)

Comment: Yet a very simple & small library to use for programmatic clicking on the links on documents is [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). But you have to learn PHP, or at least get to become familiar with it

Comment: Thanks! I tried Selenium IDE with Firefox. I'm still trying to figure out what's the right command to get it to 'click' on every link, but I'm trying. I tried recording and it didn't work.